# Returning results of LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

New to LINQ but this should be fairly simple.

I'm pulling a recordset of products from the DB:

```
ReportData= topProductsController.GetWowDetails(CurrentUser.UserId, _companyGroupCode, sector, year, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

and from that recordset I'm trying to group the results by the product ID and count:

```
var productCounts = (from record in wowReportData
                        group record by record.ProductID into grouping
                                 select new topProduct { Name = grouping.Key, quantity = grouping.Count() });
```

Here's the class I'm trying to return:

```
public class topProduct
{
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public topProduct(string productDesc, int downloadCount)
    {
        this.Name = productDesc;
        this.quantity = downloadCount;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to return a list of these from the function.  The current error is that:

> topProduct does not contain a constructor that takes 0 parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is failing is because you are using the property initializer way to set values to your properties, and at least in the way you called it (`new topProduct {...`) it will first initialize the object using the default constructor. But you don't have one.

Change to this:

```
var productCounts = (from record in wowReportData
                     group record by record.ProductID into grouping
                     select new topProduct(grouping.Key, grouping.Count()));
```

Or add a default constructor (which that is what I'd do) and then you can use it as you did

```
public class topProduct
{
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //default constructor
    public topProduct() {}

    public topProduct(string productDesc, int downloadCount)
    {
        this.Name = productDesc;
        this.quantity = downloadCount;
    }
}
```

---

The use of `()` if for when you are initializing an object and you call a constructor - `()` being the default constructor (with no parameters). This one is created automatically in the case you have not created any other constructor. [See here about constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx).

Now in C# 3.5 if I'm not mistaking they introduced the ability to initialize properties inline with the initialization of the object and thus to save you the pain of creating a big array of constructors for all the different options. But that is just a nice syntactic sugar for:

```
var obj = new Class() { Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = 2 };
        ||
var obj = new Class();
obj.Prop1 = "a";
obj.Prop2 = 2;
```

Then they even enabled you to remove the empty `()` (in the case that the constructor you are calling is the default constructor) and you turn out to have: `var obj = new Class { Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = 2 };` but you can't do this if you don't have a default constructor like in your original case.

Comment: Dude, nice.  Like I said, new to LINQ, so when do we use {} instead of ()?

Comment: Thanks much Gilad!

Comment: @Trevor: This is not a LINQ specific issue. It's about basic C# syntax and understanding which constructor(s) get invoked depending on which syntax you use to initialize an object. See: [How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx).

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild - Please consider marking question as solved :)